# mysqldump will not export an individual database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export a database using mysqldump from command line. I am using the following syntax:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword databasename > outputfile.sql
```

I've tried several variations on this, but I always end up with the following as the contents of the output file:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
```

I can get mysqldump to export all of my databases if I exclude the database name, but it will not export just a single database.

Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: `mysqldump --databases databasename` doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, I've tried  `mysqldump ... --databases databasename`

Comment: What is the name of your database? Does it contain some special characters that mysqldump doesn't like.  I use the same set up as you do with no problem, except I use -h hostname because the database is on a different host.

Comment: That is correct syntax. I'd guess that `mysqldump` is picking up some other options somewhere. Maybe it's a shell alias with an option like `-A` included in the alias definition? Try running `\mysqldump ...` to run it un-aliased.

Comment: @Robbert, just an underscore, but I've tried it with another database with no special characters.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Doesn't appear to be an alias. I just tried using `\mysqldump` but no luck. It doesn't even throw an error if I use the wrong password, so it doesn't even appear to be trying. It just tells me my syntax is wrong even though it's not.

Comment: What happens when you do `mysqldump databasename`? I would expect an access denied.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky - Same output. `Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] ...`

Comment: What is the output of `alias`? It might be a few things, but is `mysqldump` in that list?

Comment: And why not also try: `which mysqldump`

Comment: @BillKarwin you were on the right track with `-A`. I tried `mysqldump --print-defaults` and apparently `--all-databases` is in the default arguments. I ran it with `--no-defaults` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troubleshooting from the comments above:

> That is correct syntax. I'd guess that mysqldump is picking up some other options somewhere. Maybe it's a shell alias with an option like -A included in the alias definition? Try running `\mysqldump ...` to run it un-aliased.

Your reply:

> @BillKarwin you were on the right track with -A. I tried mysqldump --print-defaults and apparently --all-databases is in the default arguments. I ran it with --no-defaults and it worked like a charm.

The problem is that `--all-databases` was configured as a default option. When you try using that option together with an argument specifying one database, it outputs the usage error you described.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html says that `all-databases` can be either a command-line flag, or an option in the config file.

I'd suggest looking in your /etc/my.cnf or $HOME/.my.cnf for the `all-databases` option. It can appear either in the `[mysqldump]` group or the `[client]` group.

Answer (score 1):

How about (without the space between `u` and `root`)

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword databasename > outputfile.sql
```

Comment: Also tried `-uroot` `--user=root` `--password=password` --- All of these work when not specifying a database and just output all of the databases. It just fails when I try adding the database parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your root password in a command line is a really bad idea. At the very least, create a .my.cnf in your home directory, setting permissions to 600 (rw for you only) containing:

```
[mysqldump]
user=root
password=yourpassword
```

This will allow you to perform that particular command without a password. Since there's no particular reason your root user needs to be doing the dump, why not just create a user that can do this?

Presumably, you're doing the mysqldump to back things up. To make life even easier on you, set it in cron as in the example below which executes at midnight. Because of the presence of the .my.cnf file containing the password, it doesn't need a password in the command

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -h localhost databasename > /home/someuser/outputfile.sql 2>&1
```